# jQuery Real Person (Captcha) getHash giving wrong hash value to use with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, captcha

I'm trying to get the hash value of the displayed text of jQuery Real Person plugin with the method $(selector).realperson('getHash'), documented on http://keith-wood.name/realPersonRef.html. However this method gives me a wrong hash value for the displayed text. My code is given below.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" id="captcha">
```

**Javascript**

```
hash_val = jQuery("#captcha").realperson('getHash');
console.log(hash_val);
```

TEXT DISPLAYED => **MEMIDH**
CONSOLE OUTPUT => **2759770256** *which is incorrect*

but when I submit the form, server value is correct.
SERVER HASH VALUE => **-1064808263** *which is correct*

what I'm really trying to do is, to get the hash value and send it via AJAX to server along with user entered text so that I can handle the form without submitting. Please help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Is your PHP build 32-bit?  Looks like integer overflow resulting in a negative value on the server side.  But 2759770256 is correct.

Comment: It's 64 bit. I Used the 64 bit algorithm on server side. any ideas drew010 ??. and thank you very much for your response... !!!

Comment: What if you run the hash on the server through `sprintf('%u', $serverHash);`  Does that print it correctly?